# Sorting, grouping, and counting dates using the java Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

How to solve the following examples using the Stream API.

```
/*
 * Calculate the total number of Mondays for the specified years grouped by month
 */
EnumMap<Month, Long> totalMondaysByMonth(int yearSince, int yearUntilInclusive);

/*
 * Issue a list of Fridays on the 13th for the specified years,
 * sorted in ascending order first by year, and second by name of the month
 */
List<LocalDate> friday13s(int yearFrom, int yearUntilInclusive);
```

My example solution:

```
public EnumMap<Month, Long> totalMondaysByMonth(int yearSince, int yearUntilInclusive) {
           return Stream.iterate(LocalDate.of(yearSince, 0, 0), date -> date.plusYears(1))
                   .limit(yearUntilInclusive)
                   .filter(x -> x.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LocalDate::getMonth, Collectors.summingLong(???));

}
```

What code should I insert in (Collectors.summingLong(???))) to count the number of Mondays?

```
public List<LocalDate> friday13s(int yearFrom, int yearUntilInclusive) {
    return Stream.iterate(LocalDate.of(yearFrom, 0, 0), date -> date.plusYears(1))
            .limit(yearUntilInclusive)
            .filter(x -> x.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY || x.getDayOfMonth() == 13)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(LocalDate::getYear).thenComparing(LocalDate::getMonth))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Tell me how to write correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your first and last sentences don't match. What's your question exactly? Can you please rephrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will only help you fix the first one, you can understand this and fix your second one too (it is almost the same).

You first say :

```
Stream.iterate(LocalDate.of(yearSince, 0, 0), date -> date.plusYears(1))
```

But do you really need to iterate *years* here? You need to find out `Mondays` (which are days, no?) That is the main problem here, since your "loop" is going to happen only as many times as that difference of years is. Let's say you want `2018-2020` interval - how many times are you going to iterate with what you have right now?

But now you need to think when to "stop" this loop - and this why you were using `limit`:

```
 .limit(yearUntilInclusive)
```

The problem is that if you would correctly iterate `days`, you do not really know when to stop, do you? Ideally, you want to stop by using a `Predicate`, like: I want to start on the first `day` of `2018` and stop on the last `day` of `2020`. `limit` can't really do that (you could via a difference of days from that `last` to that `first` - I'll let you figure out how). Or, I find easier to use a `Predicate` with `takeWhile` (requires at least java-9).

Then that `Collectors.summingLong` can be made as an `Collectors.summingInt` (you would need *a lot* of years to jump from `32` bits integer to `64` bits long). And what do you need to do there? For each days that you have a match, simply add one. Simply "adding one" is also called `counting` and there is a collector for that `Collectors.counting()` that you can use also.

And the last point is that `EnumMap` can take a `Map` as a parameter to its constructor; as such:

```
public static EnumMap<Month, Integer> totalMondaysByMonth(int yearSince, int yearUntilInclusive) {

    return Stream.iterate(LocalDate.of(yearSince, 1, 1), date -> date.plusDays(1))
                 .takeWhile(date -> date.getYear() <= yearUntilInclusive)
                 .filter(x -> x.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
                 .collect(
                     Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                         Collectors.groupingBy(LocalDate::getMonth, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)),
                         EnumMap::new
                     )
                 );
}
```

But can you be more effective here? You could find the first Monday in the year you start from and iterate weeks from that, not days:

```
 LocalDate firstMonday = LocalDate.of(yearSince, 1, 1).with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
 EnumMap<Month, Integer> right =
        Stream.iterate(firstMonday, date -> date.plusWeeks(1))
              .takeWhile(date -> date.getYear() <= yearUntilInclusive)
              .collect(
                  Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                      Collectors.groupingBy(LocalDate::getMonth, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)),
                      EnumMap::new
                  )
              );
```

Comment: Thank you, you are well explained. I think I can do the second task myself and close the topic.

Comment: Is `.filter(x -> x.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY)` still necessary when you’re doing `Stream.iterate(firstMonday, date -> date.plusWeeks(1))` in the first place? And mind that `Stream.iterate(a, b).takeWhile(c)` can be replaced by `Stream.iterate(a, c, b)`…

Comment: And `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(LocalDate::getMonth, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)), EnumMap::new)` does not only bear an unnecessary copy operation, it may fail when the result map is empty. So better use `Collectors.groupingBy(LocalDate::getMonth, () -> new EnumMap<>(Month.class), Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1))`. And since this requires Java 9 anyway, there is no advantage in using `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)` instead of `counting()`. The OP’s original code already had a `EnumMap<Month, Long>` return type.

Comment: @Holger indeed that filter can be replaced. I also agree on the `Stream.iterate(a,b,c)` - I though about that, but sounded like already too many suggestions. That `EnumMap` suggestion though, is very much like!

Comment: More idiomatic and even slightly more efficient: `EnumMap<Month, Long> right = firstMonday.datesUntil(firstMonday.withYear(yearUntilInclusive+1), Period.ofWeeks(1)) .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LocalDate::getMonth, () -> new EnumMap<>(Month.class), Collectors.counting()));`